# Edit CSS in WPF Webbrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I want to build a lightweight (wysiwyg) css editor based on the WPF webbrowser control, so I need to be able to manipulate the css. I figure you can get the HtmlDOM from the Webbrowser.Document property, however i'm having some difficulty figuring out how to obtain and edit the document's css.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate each  element and gets the style sheet property, then use IHTMLStyleSheet::cssText to get or set the css.

Answer (score 0):

You might find my [CSS parser component for .NET](http://www.modeltext.com/css/) useful.